# SQL - how to correctly implement LEFT Join with Inner Joins

Tags: sql, sql-server, left-join, inner-join, ssms

I have two tables of information. One is present in the system and another is being imported to compare and update the information. I am trying to use a Right Join to get the information that is in Table B that is NOT in Table A. I need to introduct the info from Table B so the output values are not NULL.

FULL CODE:

```
Select TDS, TL, IK
From (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME As TDS, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY) As A
RIGHT JOIN Sheet1 B
On A.TDS=B.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET
Where A.TDS is Null
```

---

Example:

**Table A**

From code:

```
Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY
```

Should produce:

```
OBJ_NAME     ITEM_CODE     IK
tds-123      tl-1234      387
tds-456      tl-8721      879
tds-983      tl-1987      928
```

---

**Table B**
With code:

```
Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
From Sheet1
Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL
```

Should produce:

```
TOOLING_DATA_SHEET   CUTTING_TOOL  ITEM_KEY
tds-123                  tl-1234      387
tds-456                  tl-8721      879
tds-983                  tl-1987      928
tds-873                  tl-9873      827
tds-982                  tl-9872      287
```

---

**What code currently gives back:**

```
TDS         TL      IK
NULL       NULL    NULL
NULL       NULL    NULL
```

**What the code should give back:**

```
TDS         TL      IK
tds-873   tl-9873   827
tds-982   tl-9872   287
```

---

**EDIT ATTEMPT AT LEFT JOIN** - not working, join for Sheet1 needs to be implemented

```
Select l.OBJ_NAME As TDS, i.ITEM_CODE As TL, i.ITEM_KEY As IK
From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS l
Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER i On i.ITEM_KEY=l.ENTITY_KEY
Left Join Sheet1 s on l.OBJ_NAME = s.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET and
                        i.ITEM_CODE = s.CUTTING_TOOL and
                        i.ITEM_KEY = i.ITEM_KEY
where s.CUTTING_TOOL is null
```

Comment: Try to use LEFT JOIN only for better readability of queries.

Comment: If I use LEFT JOIN, the line where it says Left Join Sheet1 B would have to change to the table with A. However the table with A is created with code from a merge of other tables `ENT_LINK_OBJECTS` and `ENT_ITEM_MASTER`. How would I reference it? @VojtěchDohnal

Comment: Just flip the tables, seems that if you need further help then better create SQL Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: When using Left Join with multiple Inner Join Statements, you can define as follows

```
Select TDS, TL, IK
From (Select Sheet1.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET As TDS, Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL As TL, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY As IK
        From Sheet1
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL) As A
Left Join (Select ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.OBJ_NAME, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE, ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY
        From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS
        Inner Join ENT_ITEM_MASTER
        On ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_KEY=ENT_LINK_OBJECTS.ENTITY_KEY) As B
On A.TDS=B.OBJ_NAME
Where B.OBJ_NAME is Null
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `left join`/`is null`:

```
select l.OBJ_NAME As TDS
     , i.ITEM_CODE As TL
     , i.ITEM_KEY As IK
from ENT_LINK_OBJECTS l
join ENT_ITEM_MASTER i on i.ITEM_KEY = l.ENTITY_KEY
left Join Sheet1 s on l.OBJ_NAME = s.TOOLING_DATA_SHEET and
                      i.ITEM_CODE = s.CUTTING_TOOL and
                      i.ITEM_KEY = s.ITEM_KEY
where s.CUTTING_TOOL is null
```

Comment: I am new to SQL so if you could help walk me through this a bit I would really appreciate it. I created the table t1 in code so I cannot reference it as t1. I'm not sure if that changes anything. I just do not know how to reference it in the from statement since there is no "t1" table... @suslov. To further clarify, Sheet1 is everything I need for table B so it is easily referenced. However my "t1" is a merge of information from `ENT_LINK_OBJECTS` and `ENT_ITEM_MASTER` in code, that you see above is set `As A` which is how I currently reference that. How would I do that with your code?

Comment: @user4888: `t1` is just an alias, you can name it like you want, just change `t1.` everywhere to `tt11.`, for example. Or whatever you like.

Comment: Oh i see, so where you say `from tableB t1` I would write `from tableB ENT_LINK_OBJECTS, ENT_ITEM_MASTER`?

Comment: @user4888: post your query then

Comment: For t1 as written in my code, it is a table made from the inner join of two tables and I need it to stay that way...how would that work? Or am I simply misunderstanding? When I try your code with my inner join, it says all of the info after the `=` could not be bound and in the where statement it also could not be bound @suslov

Comment: my query  meaning  my code? That is in the question above @suslov

Comment: just chain `ENT_LINK_OBJECTS` -> `inner join` ->  `ENT_ITEM_MASTER` -> `left join` -> `tableA`

Comment: Sorry if I did not clarify that correctly. I need the inner join because it matches the `OBJ_NAME` to its correct `ITEM_CODE` using `ITEM_KEY`. That is why the inner join needs to stay as far as I understand @suslov

Comment: Use `inner  join` for this merge and then use `left join` for merging with `tableA`, simple as that.

Comment: I have edited the question to show my current attempt with trying that code out. It leaves several unbound errors. Where is this incorrect? @suslov

Comment: Thank you for updating to clarify. That definitely helped. However, I still get the same errors: after the first two `=` it says`multi-part identifier could not be found ` and the same for after the `where` statement @suslov

Comment: @user4888: You've referenced an alias, but still used table name, that caused your error. Updated the query.

Comment: @user4888: Have you succeeded?

Comment: thank you for your help. that gets rid of the errors but now my output for the table is nothing. where i think the issue is, is that for sheet1, it is also inner joined with the ENT_ITEM_MASTER table with and inner join of `ENT_ITEM_MASTER.ITEM_CODE=Sheet1.CUTTING_TOOL`. Would that be where the issue is? @suslov

Comment: @user4888: That is just too much for one question, sorry.

Comment: thank you for your help with the Left Join idea. I have figured it out as posted below

Answer (score 0):

try this query

```
select a.* from tableb a
right join tablea b on a.tooling_data_sheet=b.obj_name
where b.obj_name is null
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider simply using `not exists`:

```
select lo.*
From ENT_LINK_OBJECTS lo
where not exists (select 1
                  from ENT_ITEM_MASTER im
                  where im.ITEM_KEY = lo.ENTITY_KEY
                 );
```

The abbreviations `lo` and `im` are called *table aliases*.  Using them is a good idea.  Sometimes they are needed; more often they just make a query easier to write and to read.  It is considered a best practice to use abbreviations of the table names for them.

Comment: the `not exists` method is definitely a good idea; however, I am not selecting everything from the LINK_OBJECTS table, I need that to be linked correctly and then delete all of the identical information that occurs in Sheet1, not a comparisson between LINK_OBJECTS and ITEM_MASTER

Comment: You can do the appropriate join and then use `not exists`.